# Google App Engine error code 204

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My Java GAE instance is getting the following errors:

> A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request,
>   causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used
>   for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)

It happened for 7 request over about 2 seconds and all to GAE Endpoints.  When I noticed the errors (a day later) I looked at the instances tab and saw that there were four instances running all with start times after the problem (all marked dynamic availability).

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365235/error-204-in-a-google-app-engine-api-in-java) but I use url fetches all the time and the problem is only occurring on the odd occassion.  It was actually happening before I started using url fetch.

I have seen other posts that suggest it is a memory error and that you should change the instance type or memory size (these also all seem to be PHP rather than Java so not sure if they are relevant).  I looked through the console and can't seem to find anywhere to do this.

I have seen post that say you should have more than one resident instance but I also can't find any console configuration for that.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Trying to increase the memory to see if that fixes it.  Added <instance-class>F2</instance-class> to the appengine-web.xml to move to the instance with twice the memory

Comment: Still getting the 204s after upping the memory so it can't be that.  Similar to before there were about 7 over a period of 6 seconds